# home.blade.php form login on left

Tags: html, css, laravel-blade

the login form in the home blade remains anchored to the left, and I need to have it in the center of the page, can you help me? the entire complete view is located in the repository

I tried with grid and styles but failed, this is a views for phpvms7

thanks for those who reply

this is the code and view [repository](https://github.com/Blackedsoul/ItaViews) :

```
@extends('app')
@section('title', __('home.welcome.title'))
@section('content')
  <div class="form">
    <h1>@lang('common.login')</h1>
    @if(Auth::check())
    {{-- Itera sugli utenti solo se l'utente è autenticato --}}
    @foreach($users as $user)
    <!-- Codice per visualizzare gli utenti autenticati -->
    @endforeach
    @else
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
           <div class="form-group" style="max-width: 100%;">>
            <label for="email">@lang('common.email')</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">@lang('Password')</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">@lang('common.login')</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endif
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfzZe.png)

Comment: Please add all relevant code (including your current CSS and what you have tried) into the question directly, not through off-site links. You should also post the generated HTML instead of the source so we can see what the actual structure of your document is.

Comment: I put the repository because the forum doesn't give me the possibility to copy all the code in full

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to center everything. Just wrap the form in a container:

Add this css to your stylsheet:

```
.form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh; /* Optional: Set a minimum height for centering vertically */
}

/* Add any additional styling for your form as needed */
.form {
  /* Your existing form styles */
}
```

Here is the modified blade template code with the flexbox wrapper:

```
@extends('app')
@section('title', __('home.welcome.title'))
@section('content')
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div class="form">
    <h1>@lang('common.login')</h1>
    @if(Auth::check())
    {{-- Itera sugli utenti solo se l'utente è autenticato --}}
    @foreach($users as $user)
    <!-- Codice per visualizzare gli utenti autenticati -->
    @endforeach
    @else
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
           <div class="form-group" style="max-width: 100%;">>
            <label for="email">@lang('common.email')</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">@lang('Password')</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">@lang('common.login')</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endif
  </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it stays anchored to the left, I tried to create a separate style but nothing

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by downloading the bootstrap file and creating a cardform in it, thanks for the answers